# Finding Window and Navigating to URL with Crossrider

Tags: javascript, tabs, crossrider

I'm rather new to Javascript and Crossrider. I believe what I'm trying to do is a rather simple thing - maybe I missed something here?

I am writing an extension that automatically logs you into Dropbox and at a later time will log you out. I can log the user into Dropbox automatically, but now my client wants me to automatically log those people out of dropbox by **FINDING** the open Dropbox windows and logging each one of them out.

He says he's seen it and it's possible.

Basically what I want is some code that allows me to get the active tabs, and set the location.href of those tabs. Or even close them. So far this is what I got:

//background.js:

appAPI.ready(function($) {

```
// Initiate background timer
backgroundTimer();

// Function to run backround task every minute
function backgroundTimer() {

    if (appAPI.db.get('logout') == true)
    {
        // retrieves the array of tabs
        appAPI.tabs.getAllTabs(function(allTabInfo) 
        {

            // loop through tabs
            for (var i=0; i<allTabInfo.length; i++) 
            {
                //is this dropbox?
                if (allTabInfo[i].tabUrl.indexOf('www.dropbox.com')!=-1)
                {
                    appAPI.tabs.setActive(allTabInfo[i].tabId);

                                    //gives me something like chrome-extension://...
                    window.alert(window.location.href);

                                    //code below doesn't work
                    //window.location.href = 'https://www.dropbox.com/logout';

                }

            }
            appAPI.db.set('logout',false);
        });
        window.alert('logged out.');
    }


    setTimeout(function() {
        backgroundTimer();
    }, 10 * 1000);
}
```

});

When I do appAPI.tabs.setActive(allTabInfo[i].tabId); and then window.alert(window.location.href); I get as address "chrome-extension://xxx" - which I believe is the address of my extension, which is totally not what I need, but rather the URL of the active window! More than that, I need to navigate the current window to the log out page... or at least refresh it. Can anybody help, please?

-Rowan R. J.

P.S.
Earlier I tried saving the window reference of the dropbox URL I opened, but I couldn't save the window reference into the appAPI.db, so I changed technique. Help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, your use of the Crossrider APIs looks good.

The issue here is that you are trying to use *window.location.href* to get the address of the active tab. However, in the background scope, the *window* object relates to the background page/tab and and not the active tab; hence you receive the URL of the background page. [Note: Scopes can't directly interactive with each others objects]

Since your objective is to change/close the URL of the active dropbox tab, you can achieve this using messaging between scopes. So, in your example you can [send a message](http://docs.crossrider.com/#!/api/appAPI.message) from the background scope to the extension page scope with the request to logout. For example (and I've taken the liberty to simplify the code):

**background.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  appAPI.setInterval(function() {
    if (appAPI.db.get('logout')) {
      appAPI.tabs.getAllTabs(function(allTabInfo) {
        for (var i=0; i<allTabInfo.length; i++) {
          if (allTabInfo[i].tabUrl.indexOf('www.dropbox.com')!=-1) {
            // Send a message to all tabs using tabId as an identifier
            appAPI.message.toAllTabs({
              action: 'logout',
              tabId: allTabInfo[i].tabId
            });
          }
        }
        appAPI.db.set('logout',false);
      });
    }
  }, 10 * 1000);
});
```

**extension.js**:

```
appAPI.ready(function($) {
  // Listen for messsages
  appAPI.message.addListener(function(msg) {
    // Logout if the tab ids match
    if (msg.action === 'logout' && msg.tabId === appAPI.getTabId()) {
      // change URL or close code
    }
  });
});
```

**Disclaimer**: I am a Crossrider employee